# finding min and max after removing percentage of num values knowing the standard deviation.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have a question 
i have some data and i know it's (number of values, min, max, mean and standard deviation)
can I know the minimum after removing x% of the total number of values
and the maximum after removing x% of total number of values
I'm not a math guy so please provide me a simple equation if you can.

Comment: Short answer: with certainty, no.

Comment: is the x% random? i assume it is, because you don't know the extrema.